# Rows to columns SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am writing a query that will be used in a .NET application, therefore I would like the SQL Server 2008 o do much of the processing for me instead of the client PC that the application will run on.

I am trying to get data from a single table with an index value, based off of that index value I would like that item to placed in a specific column.

Here is an example:

table MAS:

```
MA      SN      Mindex
B275    7A1515  1
B276    7A1515  2
E530    7A1515  3
B291    7A1519  1
B292    7A1519  2
E535    7A1519  3
B301    7A2515  1
B302    7A2515  2
B331    7A2519  1
B332    7A2519  2
```

Here is the output I would like:

```
 SN      mi1     mi2     mi3
 7A1515  B275    B276    E530
 7A1519  B291    B292    E535
 7A2515  B301    B302    null
 7A2519  B331    B332    null
```

I tried doing the following query, it works with items with 3 indexes but if there are only two, it fills it with random data.

```
 select mas1.SN, mas1.MA as mi1,mas2.MA as mi2, mas3.MA as mi3
 from MAS ma1, MAS ma2, MAS ma3
 where mas1.SN = '7A1515' and mas1.Mindex = '1' and mas2.Mindex = '2' and mas3.Mindex = '3'
```

I was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction as I am still fairly new at writing these advanced queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are on SQL Server 2008 you can also use `PIVOT` but the old style way of doing it is often easier IMO.

```
SELECT 
    SN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Mindex=1 THEN MA END) AS mi1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Mindex=2 THEN MA END) AS mi2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Mindex=3 THEN MA END) AS mi3
FROM MAS
GROUP BY SN
```